# How can i install a new version of apk file on a device without losing the previous data

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am new in Cordova Phonegap and I am trying to install a new apk and replacing the old one. Each time a new version is installed, the old data is lost. How can I install an apk file without losing the previous data.

Please help phonegap experts. I need your help.

Comment: What data is being lost? When you say install a new version what do you mean: are you uninstalling the old version and installing the new one or just installing the new version over the old one?

Comment: I modified in some files and again i build a new apk with a new version and i am replacing it over the new one @HuskyHuskie,

Comment: What you are describing is an update (uninstall then install) but should not purge the application's data. Something else must be going on. How are you updating your app?

Comment: Is this just running from your command line on a local device? or are we talking something over an device management solution?

Comment: Please add me on gmail or message me on gmail: my gmail id is:anant.n.padhi@gmail.com,so that we can have a better chat discussion there.